# My comment system won't add content to my database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am creating a comment system for every post that is on my site.  I want this system to recognize the user that is logged in so all they have to do is write their comment and the code will automatically add their user_id and associate the comment with the post along with adding the comment.

In my comments table I have:

id - int auto increment

idea_id - int (This is the post id)

user_id - int

comment - mediumtext

---

I have a basic web form :

```
<?php

include 'comment.php';

?>      
<form method = 'Post'>

    Comment: <br/>
    <input type = 'text' name = 'comment' id = 'comment' autocomplete= 'off' />
    <input type = 'submit' name = 'submit' value = 'Comment' /> 
</form>
```

---

Then comment.php is:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $comment = $_POST['comment'];
        $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];



        if(empty($comment)) {
            $message = "You Haven't Written Anything";
    } else {
        if(isset($_GET['user_id'])) {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $_GET['user_id'];
    }
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments VALUES('', '".$user_id."', '".$comment."') ");
        $message = "OK! Thanks for leaving your comment!";  
    }   

        echo "<div class = 'box'>$message</div>";
    }
    ?>
```

Right now I only have it adding the user_id and comment because I was trying to troubleshoot the problem.  I also have no idea how to get the code to identify the post.  Thank you very much to anybody who can help me with this.

Comment: add a hidden form field for the idea_id

Comment: You should add a hidden field to the form with the post ID.

Comment: And you should read up on sql injection.

Comment: does the comment contain `'`? Suggestion, [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: from where are you getting idea_id ? in the form, try saving it as a hidden feild, whose value can be obtained in comment.php through post method. also put you sql like this sql="insert into comments (idea_id, user_id, comment) values ('.$idea_id.','.$user_id.','.$comment.')"

Comment: Sidenote #1: Missing `session_start();` but I'll bet it's hidden somewhere, right? If not, then it is required to be inside ALL files and at the top when using sessions `$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];` etc.

Comment: Sidenote #2: You shouldn't rely on `mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments VALUES('', '".$user_id."', '".$comment."') ");` - It's kind of like hoping you shoot a dozen golf balls at night, and hope they all land in their respective holes.

Comment: The idea id is associated with every post.  How would I go about adding a hidden form.  I am not sure as to how to do that.  The session start is on another page which is included on this page.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean about the mysql_query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 <form method ='Post' Action='comment.php' name='comment_form' >

Comment: <br/>
<input type ='text' name='comment' value='' id='comment' autocomplete= 'off' />
<input type ='submit' name ='submit' value = 'Comment' /> 
</form>
```

in this code you forgot value ='' , and action='your file'

and use this php code

```
  <?php
   session_start() ;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $comment = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment']);
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];



    if(empty($comment)) {
       echo "You Haven't Written Anything";

} else {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments ( idea_id,user_id,comment) VALUES('', '".$user_id."', '".$comment."') ") or die(mysql_error());
    echo "OK! Thanks for leaving your comment!";  
    if(isset($_GET['user_id'])) {
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $_GET['user_id']; /// this is wrong here , user can enter manually id via link and you will let him be in session ???
}


}   

    //echo "<div class = 'box'>$message</div>";
}
?>
```

Comment: id - int auto increment /    idea_id - int /    user_id - int /    comment - mediumtext

Comment: THAT WORKED! Dude your the best!!!!!!  Thank you for sticking with me.  I was so confused and I'm so happy we were able to figure this out.

Comment: What do you suggest I do to add the idea_id into this table?

Comment: The comment time is a good call.  The ideas are essentially posts.  I only want to include the id for those so when I display the comments they are only the comments associated with that post

Comment: could I use a post function to get the idea_id?

Comment: I did this and I got the same message 'column count doesn't match value count at row 1'

Comment: I'm still having this issue.  But if I add the id in the parenthesis before the VALUES.  The data gets inserted into the database but the idea_id is always 0.

Comment: I added the id because nothing would get inserted otherwise. Without id I kept getting the error 'column count doesn't match value count at row 1' Otherwise it worked minus the idea_id.

Comment: mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments (id, idea_id, user_id, comment, data, time) VALUES ('', '".idea_id."', '".$user_id."', '".$comment."', now(), now() ") or die (mysql_error());  This one with id worked.  When I took id out like you said I got the error

Comment: This still makes the idea_id = 0

Comment: I asked a new question and included the code.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21768174/how-do-i-insert-an-post-id-into-a-mysql-database

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I think your problem is that you haven't connected to MySQL - If you have connected but just haven't included it, try writing

```
mysql_query("QUERYHERE") or die(mysql_error());
```

and let us know your error.

If you need to connect, the functions you require is:

```
mysql_connect("host", "user", "password");
mysql_select_db("database");
```