# How do I insert an post_id into a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, comments

I have a comment system that should input an id, an idea_id, a user_id, a comment, the data, and the time.  Everything seems to work except every time I post a comment the idea_id is always 0.  By the way an idea is basically a post.

I did this using:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $comment = $_POST['comment'];
        $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $idea_id = $_POST['idea_id'];


        if(empty($comment)) {
            $message = "You Haven't Written Anything";
    } else {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments (idea_id, user_id, comment, date, time) VALUES('".$idea_id."', '".$user_id."', '".$comment."', now(), now()) ") or die (mysql_error());
        $message = "OK! Thanks for leaving your comment!";  
        if(isset($_GET['user_id'])) {
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $_GET['user_id'];
    }

    }   

        echo "<div class = 'box'>$message</div>";
    }
    ?>  



<form method = 'Post'  name = 'comment_form'>

    Comment: <br/>
    <input type = 'text' name = 'comment' id = 'comment' autocomplete= 'off' />
    <input type = 'hidden' name = 'idea_id' value = '<?php echo $idea_id; ?>' />
    <input type = 'submit' name = 'submit' value = 'Comment' /> 
</form>
```

Comment: Be sure to sanitize your inputs. This is a very insecure way of adding input to your database. You will want to research SQL injection.

Comment: Where are you setting `$idea_id` when creating the form?

Comment: This `value = '$idea_id'` should either be `value = 'idea_id'` or `value = '<?php echo $idea_id; ?>'` yet am leaning more towards `value = '<?php echo $idea_id; ?>'`

Comment: Yep.  I already changed that in my actual code.  I'm going to edit this code.

Comment: What is your `idea_id` column set to, and is it an `AUTO_INCREMENT` by any chance, or linked to a foreign key? @user3167386

Comment: Plus, you're not loading `session_start();` as per `$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];` @user3167386 - most probably the reason.

Comment: I have this connected to another page that connects to the local host and the database that this table is in.

Comment: the idea_id column is set to int (11).

Comment: I tested your code and added `session_start();` on top plus I modified `$idea_id = $_POST['idea_id'];` to `$idea_id = $_POST['idea_id'] = "IDEA_ID";` <=(as a test) and the source contained `IDEA_ID` @user3167386 - Source => `<input type = 'hidden' name = 'idea_id' value = 'IDEA_ID' />` so that's the problem.

Comment: And if that doesn't fix it, then it's the method you're using. Where is `$_GET['user_id']` getting populated from? @user3167386 - This `$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];` and `if(isset($_GET['user_id']))` do not match by the way.

Comment: with the session start I got the error that a session was already on and it ignored the session start

Comment: This also prints IDEA_ID which I don't want.  The idea id should be a number

Comment: You're either not showing us your full or actual code, or you're using something above that, or an include.

Comment: `IDEA_ID` was MY own test, to prove that it works. You have to change it back to what it was. And it won't print, it's already in your hidden attribute. I don't know which results you're looking for.

Comment: My guess is that you have to change `$idea_id = $_POST['idea_id'];` to `$idea_id = $_REQUEST['idea_id'];`or `$idea_id = $_GET['idea_id'];` You can also try `$user_id = (isset($_GET['user_id'])) ? $_GET['user_id'] : $_SESSION['user_id'];` - where is `$idea_id` supposed to be coming from, a FORM? A DB query? A `GET` from an `href`?

Comment: I got it.  Thank You all so much.  I was stuck on this for so long.

Comment: And the final problem/solution was what? @user3167386

Comment: It was that a variable on one of the pages included on this one was defined wrong.

Comment: And how did you define it, what is the code? @user3167386

Answer (score 0):

you should define the `$idea_id` in your form and then pass it to your form

```
 $idea_id = "your_idea_id";  
 <input type = 'hidden' name = 'idea_id' value = '<?php echo $idea_id;?>' />
```

if you wanna see if it works , just try with any number like that

```
  <input type = 'hidden' name = 'idea_id' value = '66' />
```

Comment: Your idea seems awesome.  But my big problem is that i don't know how to get the idea_id.  I tried to use the POST method but that still inserted 0.

Comment: your `$idea_id = $_POST['idea_id'];` in comment.php is good. try echo `$_POST['idea_id']` before inserting it to database , if you find it 0 then your problem is in the form , your variable idea_id in the form is 0 .

Comment: I did that and nothing got printed.

Comment: then check your form , print $idea_id before the form , and see if there is some value.

Comment: when you tried with 66 , you got it inserted to database ?

Comment: It worked with 66.  But when I put the idea_id back just like in your code suggestion it gave me the error: 'unidentified variable user_id'  This error is referring to the idea_id in the value of the hidden form

Comment: then all is good in comment.php your problem is with $idea_id in your form , you are not defining your variable. you just put it there and maybe he is null or no value. Please fix your variable idea_id before making it in the form .

Comment: I think that the problem is that if I don't define idea_id before my mysql_query statement, then the $idea_id variable there is undefined. This means I would have to take out the definition of idea_id in the form.

Comment: I got it.  Everybody that answered indirectly helped me.  Thank you

Comment: What was it exactly, I for one am real curious to know. @user3167386

Comment: @user3167386 nice you got it.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like you're keeping a running count of how many ideas are going through your form.

I would suggest you allow the database to manage the idea_id for you and it be a primary key.

How would your application handle duplicate idea_ids?

Comment: When an idea/post is created, it is given an id.  That is how each one is able to be displayed separately.

Answer (score 0):

The value for the hidden input should be inside php tags:

```
<input type = 'hidden' name = 'idea_id' value = '<?php echo $idea_id;?>' />
```

This way the query won't see the idea_id as a string.

Also as stated by echo_Me you should define the variable somewhere.